# Extraction of sound features for goodness of pronunciation evaluation

Tags: audio, voice, speech

I'm working on concept of Mobile application for children logopaedic exercises (goodness of pronunciation evaluation). In first iteration we want implement evaluation of correct pronunciation of one isolated consonant (russian equivalent of  English “sh” [ʃ] sound). Result could be “correct” or “incorrect” (better points, e.g. from 1 to 5).

We have ~50 samples recorded by speech therapists and marked in 5 points quality measure. Each sample contains separate sound (0.5-2 seconds). We can get more samples in future.

In general, I split this problem in following **steps**:

1. Preprocess sound signal (reduce noise, amplify/attenuate, remove silent periods);
2. Extract proper signal features which are correlated with consonant pronunciation quality. Features are vector of numbers produced from sound chunk (frame). Feature candidates: frequency spectrum of a sound, MFCC coefficients, amplitude spectrum,... Another question is feature frame size (time duration).
3. Use some classification algorithm ("Machine learning" in general) to make classification based on features from sound training set.

The main **problem** I stacked with is lack of methodology how to **extract features**.

I have tried to use the MFCC approach, but it seems, that feature vector depends more on sound intensity variation during sample (Frankly, I did that conclusions just looking on plots of MFCC coefficients like https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzBavyZHrcMlS0xLQ2phbmxoRVk/view?usp=sharing where X values are 13 MFCC coefficients and each line represents one sound frame of 25 ms).

I am not sure in pure spectrum characteristics, because of noise nature of consonants.

A lot of papers and blog posts describes problem of speech recognition in word and utterance context. My intuition says that I need different approach for my problem.

Examples of good features for similar tasks and general methodology of features evaluation will be both usable for me. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, how did you reduce noise?

Comment: Hi, I've tried some filtering, but the sound itself has noise nature. So, noise filtering is a problem, which I'm ignoring now.
Here is sound [sample](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzBavyZHrcMlemVUc2dtaWpLcVU/view?usp=sharing).

I did only silence trim and average power normalization.

Comment: let's say you are given a sound file like this. https://soundcloud.com/user-798907028/myogyi what could you do to reduce the background sheeeee sound for a bit?

Comment: As I understand, a general approach is to frame sound in time and reduce those frequencies which levels are similar to their average on the entire sound.
Please, check sample I've placed in the previous comment. Do you think noise filtering is a critical problem here?